# WPF, handle with error and warning message

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling

I need advance. I send HTTP GET request and parse HTML response, if HTML response(html string) consist some substring, I want sent to client app,(WPF app) some error/warning message.

In my solution, if html string consist some substring I throw new exception, it is stupid, what solution is suitable for this problem?

code is here:

```
class MyClass
{
//.....

private bool SendRp(string postData)
  {
    bool result = false;

    const string parameters = @"&lok=1&rpI=3";
    string htmlStringResult = HttpPostReq(
      new Uri(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}{1}{2}", PokecUrl.Rp, Account.SessionId, parameters)), postData);
    try
    {
      if (htmlStringResult.ToLower(new CultureInfo("sk-Sk")).Contains("is is empty"))
      {
        throw new ArgumentException("ID is empty!");
      }
      if (htmlStringResult.ToLower(new CultureInfo("sk-Sk")).Contains("id does not exist"))
      {
        throw new ArgumentException("ID does not exist.");
      }
      if (htmlStringResult.ToLower(new CultureInfo("sk-Sk")).Contains("blocked"))
      {
        throw new WebException("Your ID is blocked!");
      }
      if (!htmlStringResult.ToLower(new CultureInfo("sk-Sk")).Contains("message was send"))
      {
        Match match = Regex.Match(htmlStringResult, @"\bhs=\w{15}\b");

        if (match.Success)
        {
          result = true;
        }
        else
        {
          throw new Exception("Some problem"); 
        }

      }
      return result;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
      throw exception;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood whats is your problem here. It is ok to throw an exception on your "web requester" class, and then catch the exception on your UI class to show a message.

The easiest way to show a message is using [MessageBox](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/msgbox08102009142422PM/msgbox.aspx):

```
MessageBox.Show("Hello MessageBox");
```

Comment: I thinking about use CodeContract.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hakoman/archive/2010/11/02/code-contracts-a-brilliant-way-to-do-validation-in-your-code-and-even-more.aspx.